# Strange characters in preview of R Notebook

Tags: r, r-markdown

When I preview my R Notebook, the HTML output contains strange characters.

This chunk code and output

[image: Chunk]

gets rendered in HTML as

[image: html]

How should I fix this?

SessionInfo:

R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk6qq.png) LC_COLLATE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252  LC_CTYPE=Dutch_Netherlands.1252    LC_MONETARY=Dutch_Netherlands.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=Dutch_Netherlands.1252

other attached packages:
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk6qq.png) plotly_4.9.0         DT_0.6               shinydashboard_0.7.1 shiny_1.3.2          lubridate_1.7.4      forcats_0.4.0
 [7] stringr_1.4.0        dplyr_0.8.1          purrr_0.3.2          readr_1.3.1          tidyr_0.8.3          tibble_2.1.1
[13] ggplot2_3.1.1        tidyverse_1.2.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pk6qq.png) tidyselect_0.2.5  xfun_0.7          haven_2.1.0       lattice_0.20-38   colorspace_1.4-1  generics_0.0.2    viridisLite_0.3.0 htmltools_0.3.6
 [9] base64enc_0.1-3   yaml_2.2.0        rlang_0.3.4       pillar_1.4.0      later_0.8.0       glue_1.3.1        withr_2.1.2       modelr_0.1.4
[17] readxl_1.3.1      plyr_1.8.4        munsell_0.5.0     gtable_0.3.0      cellranger_1.1.0  rvest_0.3.4       htmlwidgets_1.3   evaluate_0.14
[25] knitr_1.23        httpuv_1.5.1      crosstalk_1.0.0   broom_0.5.2       Rcpp_1.0.1        xtable_1.8-4      scales_1.0.0      backports_1.1.4
[33] promises_1.0.1    jsonlite_1.6      mime_0.6          hms_0.4.2         digest_0.6.19     stringi_1.4.3     grid_3.6.0        cli_1.1.0
[41] tools_3.6.0       magrittr_1.5      lazyeval_0.2.2    crayon_1.3.4      pkgconfig_2.0.2   data.table_1.12.2 xml2_1.2.0        rmarkdown_1.13
[49] assertthat_0.2.1  httr_1.4.0        rstudioapi_0.10   R6_2.4.0          nlme_3.1-139      compiler_3.6.0

Comment: Seems like a bug in the render process since the codes coincide with the text colors. Try to update RStudio, Knitr and Rmarkdown if not done already.

Comment: I have the latest versions of R, RStudio, Knitr and RMarkdown. I've added part of the SessionInfo to my question.

Comment: I've noticed that on RStudio Cloud I have the same problem.