# R notebook tibble output from code chunk corrupted when paged.print = FALSE

Tags: r, rstudio, tibble, rnotebook

I want to create a R Notebook and also output code chunks displaying a tibble. When I set the paged.print parameter in the code chunk to FALSE, the output looks corrupted.

The weird thing is, yesterday I'm 100% sure that I was able to create tibble outputs that looked perfectly fine.

I also googled and found that this issue is known but seemed to have been solved already in earlier version of RStudio:

https://community.rstudio.com/t/previewing-a-tibble-in-an-r-notebook/36752
[Strange characters in preview of R Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56492132/strange-characters-in-preview-of-r-notebook)
https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2748

Any idea why it is not working for me?

**Example**

````
---
title: "R Notebook"
output: html_notebook
---

```{r paged.print = FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
dat <- as_tibble(data.frame(x = rep(1,10),
                            y = rep("A", 10)))

dat
```
````

**Current output**

```
[38;5;246m# A tibble: 10 x 2[39m
       x y    
   [3m[38;5;246m<dbl>[39m[23m [3m[38;5;246m<fct>[39m[23m
[38;5;250m 1[39m     1 A    
[38;5;250m 2[39m     1 A    
[38;5;250m 3[39m     1 A    
[38;5;250m 4[39m     1 A    
[38;5;250m 5[39m     1 A    
[38;5;250m 6[39m     1 A    
[38;5;250m 7[39m     1 A    
[38;5;250m 8[39m     1 A    
[38;5;250m 9[39m     1 A    
[38;5;250m10[39m     1 A
```

**Expected output**

```
# A tibble: 10 x 2
       x y    
   <dbl> <fct>
 1     1 A    
 2     1 A    
 3     1 A    
 4     1 A    
 5     1 A    
 6     1 A    
 7     1 A    
 8     1 A    
 9     1 A    
10     1 A
```

Sys.info():

```
   sysname        release        version       machine
 "Windows"       "10 x64"  "build 18363"      "x86-64"
```

R-Version: 3.6.3
RStudio-Version: 1.2.5033

Comment: Can you give us your `Sys.info()`?

Comment: updated with the sys info above

Comment: Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in Rstudio:

Global options -> Console

change ANSI Escape Codes to "Show ANSI Colors".

Comment: Fixed by changing **ANSI Escape Codes:** to *Remove ANSI codes*. Global Options -> Console